# Partial and Final Validation of NSTextField with NumberFormatter's minimum property

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nsnumberformatter

I think I'm missing something about how `NumberFormatters` interact with `NSTextFields`.

I want a `NSTextField` that takes integer values from 2 to 60 and it works for the most part.

The `NSTextField` is connected to my `NSNumberFormatter` subclass instance and has all its properties set correctly. I use the delegate to allow users to use the arrow keys to increment and decrement the value.

The number formatter implements `isPartialStringValid(_ partialString: String, newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?)` to allow only the digits to be entered.

The only problem I have is that it is impossible to type `10`, because when you type the first digit `1`, the formatter goes 1 is lower than the minimum of 2, so the value is illegal and nothing happens.

What I'd really like is for it to be impossible to type a number higher than 60 (which works fine) but only validate the minimum when the enter key is pressed. If the number is lower than the minimum and error message should be presented (via `NSError`).

I can, however, only find a way of always showing an error message or never. Is there some kind of mechanism for saying "check this immediately" and "check this only upon enter"?

Or is there an altogether better way of accepting partially correct input that I'm missing?

Comment: check this immediately: `isPartialStringValid(_:newEditingString:errorDescription:)`, check this only upon enter (or on exit): `getObjectValue(_:for:errorDescription:)`.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that completely.. then again it's getObjectValue isn't where you'd be looking for validation :-)